# Lyx: SVG files on PDF

Tags: graphics, pdf, lyx, svg

I'm having trouble getting an SVG diagram to appear in a PDF. From researching online it looks like it should be simple enough, but I'm yet to discover what I'm doing wrong.

I'm working in LyX, and inserting graphics I drew in Inkscape. The image does then appear in my LyX code. However, when I compile to a PDF (pdfLaTeX - though other compilers don't work either), there is only a blank space where the image file should be.

Very frustrating, since it took some time to even get the image to appear in LyX, and I assumed that had solved the problem.

**Long story short:**
Working in LyX, I can insert an SVG file I made in Inkscape - it appears in LyX's gui but it doesn't appear when compiled by pdfLaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Comment: Works here! Maybe you give some more details (OS, version of LyX, version of Inkscape...)

Comment: Check out Tools -> Settings -> File-Handling -> Converters. Do you have there any entries for SVG files. What version of LYX do you use?

Comment: Windows 7, LyX 2.0.5.1
Here's what I have under SVG -> PDF (pdflatex) converter:
_inkscape --file=$$p/$$i --export-area-drawing --without-gui --export-pdf=$$p/$$o_

Comment: Does Inkscape run at the command line? If not, you probably need to add its directory to your path.

Comment: We'll need feedback on the question WillAdams poses to help further: does this work at the command line? Without that, we can't tell if the issue is with Lyx or with your Inkscape set up.